# How to find different size icon for a certain app on the itunes app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes

I need to create a widget where different size of an apps icon is needed, how do I find them in different sizes? The only thing I have is the itunes app link like the following

```
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/yelp/id284910350?mt=8
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a Regular Expression to find the
   URL of the image, in this case,
   http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/012/Purple/42/80/fc/mzi.dqbtrgug.175x175-75.jpg.
2. Download the data using NSURLConnection.
3. Use UIImage to resize the image.